# Computing Gram-Schmidt of a matrix A with custom function in Python distorts A

Tags: python

I implemented classical Gram-Schmidt process as following:

```
def cgs(A):
    '''
    Implements classical Gram-Schmidt process.

    Inputs
        A: numpy.ndarray of shape (M, N)
    
    Outputs
        Q: numpy.ndarray of shape (M, N)
        R: numpy.ndarray of shape (N, N)
    '''
    print(A)

    M, N = A.shape
    Q = np.zeros((M, N))
    R = np.zeros((N, N))

    for i in range(N):
        v_i = A.T[i]
        for j in range(i):
            v_i -= np.inner(Q.T[j], A.T[i]) * Q.T[j]
        Q.T[i] = v_i / np.linalg.norm(v_i, ord=2)

    print(A)

    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(i, N):
            R[i][j] = np.inner(A.T[j], Q.T[i])
    
    return Q, R
```

In the main routine, I ran the code below:

```
A = np.array([[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]], dtype=np.float64)
Q, R = cgs(A)
print(Q)
print(R)
print(Q @ R)
```

When I ran this code, printed result is as following:

```
[[1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1.]]
[[ 1.          0.5        -0.66666667]
 [ 1.         -0.5         0.66666667]
 [ 0.          1.          0.66666667]]
[[ 0.70710678  0.40824829 -0.57735027]
 [ 0.70710678 -0.40824829  0.57735027]
 [ 0.          0.81649658  0.57735027]]
[[ 1.41421356e+00  1.34015774e-16  7.08401324e-17]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  1.22474487e+00 -4.68509055e-17]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.15470054e+00]]
[[ 1.          0.5        -0.66666667]
 [ 1.         -0.5         0.66666667]
 [ 0.          1.          0.66666667]]
```

First two matrices are the results of `print(A)` that are in the function `cgs`, and last three matrices are the results of main routine.

What I wonder here is that the results of two `print(A)` in the function `cgs` are not same even though there isn't any code that changes the value of `A` between two `print(A)`.

Can anyone help me to figure it out?

I have no idea what is going on here.

Comment: `A.T` and `A.T[i]` are only views but not copies of `A`, therefore `v_i -=...` modifies the matrix.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks. I solved the problem with `v_i = A.T[i].copy()`.